# Confusion regarding do Carmo's section on Ruled surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces

Similarly to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203195/do-carmos-definition-of-line-of-striction-is-proof-of-independence-on-directri), I don't really get the way lines of striction are introduced in Differential geometry of curves and surfaces.

Specifically, it is stated that a curve $\beta(t)$ being contained in the trace of a ruled surface parametrized by $x : I\times \mathbb{R}$,  $x(t, v) =\alpha(t) + vw(t)$ is equivalent to the existance of some $u(t)$ such that

\begin{align*}
\beta(t) = \alpha(t) + u(t)w(t)
\end{align*}

I understand that this is required in this case, since we eventualy want $\beta$ to be a directrix of this surface. But in general wouldn't curves such as

\begin{align*}
\gamma(v) = x(t_0, v)
\end{align*}

for fixed $t_0 \in I$ contradict this requirement?

Comment: You certainly are misstating what DoCarmo stated. He never says that *every* curve $\beta$ contained in the ruled surface is of that form — yes, the rulings, as you pointed out are indeed not of that form. He is looking for different candidates for the *directrix* of the ruled surface; he wants to single out a particular such choice of $\beta$ so that $\beta'(t)$ is orthogonal to $w'(t)$.